# How to force JavaScript as disabled on a webpage depending on browser (i.e. on Blackberry 8300)?

Tags: javascript, blackberry

I have some [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) that doesn't work correctly on the [Blackberry 8300](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_Curve_8300). The page renders differently if JavaScript is disabled. However, I'd like to be able to have the page render the "JavaScript disabled" version also if the user is on a Blackberry 8300 or on a media of type "handheld".

Is there some way I can do this? Or some check I can do? Can I detect whether the media is "handheld" and if so, to render the non-JavaScript version of the page?

For example, some if case where if media==handheld, then .. SOME HTML HERE ..

Or is there some way to "degrade" a browser to an older version?

Answer (score 1):

In pure HTML you have the `<noscript>` tag. Any other form of conditional output will have to be done on the server in another language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can check [User Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) in the HTML header.

Blackberry's browser identifies itself as something like: `BlackBerry8700/4.1.0 Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1`. Just check whether "BlackBerry" is a substring.

There is a incomplete [List of user agents for mobile phones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_user_agents_for_mobile_phones).